# Why does my custom event's data not get passed?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass additional data to my `CustomEvent` so that other items can hook into it and create logic based on what's in there. Here's what I have:

```js
$(window).on('contentRemoved', (event) => {
  console.log(event.some_data);
});


$('#trigger').on('click', () => {
  const contentRemovedEvent = new CustomEvent('contentRemoved', {
    'some_data': 1
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(contentRemovedEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="trigger">Click me</button>
```

...but it comes back as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not using [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I don't know what I don't know. What does it do better? Also it seems that this TRIGGERS an event, not create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass an object with a `detail` key : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Event_bubbling

> To add more data to the event object, the CustomEvent interface exists
>   and the detail property can be used to pass custom data.

The second param you pass to `CustomEvent` is like an `options` object, where you can specify `data` and `bubbles` .., [check the list of possible properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent#Properties) the `data` goes into the `detail` key

```js
$(window).on('contentRemoved', (event) => {
  console.log(event.detail);
});


$('#trigger').on('click', () => {
  const contentRemovedEvent = new CustomEvent('contentRemoved', {
    detail : { 'some_data': 1 }
  });
  window.dispatchEvent(contentRemovedEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="trigger">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Aha! An object...within an object with a certain key! Any explanation as to why this is?

Comment: @coolpasta check the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Comment: @coolpasta i elaborated a bit more, check the link attached for more in depth details